# Python 3.6.3 installation issue on oracle linux

Tags: python, linux, oracle

Am using oracle linux 6.7. Trying to install python 3.6.3

I tried with all possible options even by remounting file system in rw mode but nothing works.

```
mount -t ext4 -o rw,remount /dev/xvda2 /
make install
make clean
make && make install
```

ended with below error:

> if test "no-framework" = "no-framework" ; then \
>                   /usr/bin/install -c python /usr/local/bin/python3.6m; \
>           else \
>                   /usr/bin/install -c -s Mac/pythonw /usr/local/bin/python3.6m; \
>           fi /usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/python3.6m': Read-only file system make: ***
>   [altbininstall] Error 1

Please help to solve the issue...

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/` is in a read-only file system. You either get a sysadmin ti fix that or install to a different, writeable location.

Comment: @Goyo How do we specify that different writable location?

Comment: @PavanDevarakonda I've never built python from sources but I guess you find it in the build documentation. Many programs have a `--prefix` option of that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace the system Python with anything else. You will break almost everything and render your system inoperable.

Rather, you should use Software Collections to install Python 3.x: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E59096/html/index.html

Python 3.6 isn't available, but I see Python 3.3, 3.4 and 3.5 so hopefully one of those is sufficient.